# Rest API should path only add new records or should it update records by removing as well

Tags: ios, swift, rest

I have a workout endpoint which contains next fields:

```
muscleGroupIds
workoutExercises
name
```

I have next params which I want to send to server with PATH verb. I printed them to console:

```
expression debugPrint(params)
["params": ["name": "0", "muscleGroupIds": ["muscle id 1", "muscle id 2, "muscle id 3"], "workoutExercises": [{
    exerciseId = workoutId_1;
    position = 0;
    sets = 1;
}, {
    exerciseId = workoutId_2;
    position = 0;
    sets = 1;
}, {
    exerciseId = workoutId_3;
    position = 0;
    sets = 1;
}
```

So now as you see it will create 3 records of muscles and 3 records of exercise.

No let's say I am going to PATH the same base url + end point path with next params (just removing from params 2 muscles and 2 exercises and keep the same muscle 1 and exercise 1 identifiers):

```
expression debugPrint(params)
["params": ["name": "0", "muscleGroupIds": ["muscle id 1"], "workoutExercises": [{
    exerciseId = workoutId_1;
    position = 0;
    sets = 1;
}
```

My question is should PATH method remove unspecified muscles and exercises which where created before.

and what for example if I will change position as well from position = 0:

```
expression debugPrint(params)
    ["params": ["name": "0", "muscleGroupIds": ["muscle id 1"], "workoutExercises": [{
        exerciseId = workoutId_1;
        position = 10;
        sets = 1;
    }
```

Should server only keep a one record in `workoutExercises` for appropriate workout.